# WP_Query Custom Post Type if Category ID Equals

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query, categories

I've setup a custom post type "slides" and I've created two categories for the slides custom post type: "slides-testimonial" (id = 7) and "slides-regular" (id=8).

I would like to run a single loop, but use a conditional statement to compare the categories. The following code is not working with is_category. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'slides',
    'posts_per_page' => 25,
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);

// retrieving the data
while($q->have_posts()){
    $q->the_post();
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,’thumbnail’, true);
    $counter++;
?>

    <li>
        <div>
        <?php
        if (is_category(7)) {
            echo 'yes';
        } else {
            echo 'no';  
        }
        ?>
        <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
        </div>
        <span style="font-size:24px;"> - Charles D., Sacramento CA</span>
        <div id="learn_more">
            <a href="<?php the_field('slide_link'); ?>">See How We Do It</a>
        </div>
    </li>

<?php }
wp_reset_query();
unset($counter);
?>
```

Comment: Are your categories a custom taxonomy?

Comment: @Nath figured it out.. use "in_category" instead of "is_category"

Comment: `wp_reset_query` should only be used with `query_posts`, use `wp_reset_postdata` instead ( inside an `if ( $q->have_posts() )`, if you never called `$q->the_post()` then what are you resetting? ). Also avoid hardcoded IDs, that code will only work on that particular install. Deleting and recreating the category, or doing an import/export will break it

Comment: @  "Tom J Nowell" good points. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out what I needed is to use "in_category" NOT "is_category".

Here is the solution:

```
<?php if (in_category(7)) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';  
} ?>
```